Why is illegal immigration so controversial in the US?
I would not have thought this would be a contentious topic, because of the word 'illegal'. Presumably everyone (except anarchists I guess) agrees that law is part of society, and the debate would be whether there should be more legal immigration or not. Yet illegal immigration was a major talking point in the recent (2024) US elections. Why?
Example. The question title is "What is Kamala Harris' position on decriminalizing illegal entry?", which does not make sense because given that the entry is illegal, obviously Harris should be against decriminalizing it (at least until she can change the law such that the entry is no longer illegal).

How does this surprise you at all? There are many things that are illegal in the USA that plenty of people think should be legal: cannabis, public nudity, not wearing masks when the government orders it. There are plenty of things that are legal that many people think should be illegal: cannabis again, hate speech, children using social media. There are many things that are illegal where many people think they should have a lesser penalty: lying on one's taxes, possession of small amounts of drugs, assaulting someone "because they were asking for it."

One might as well ask why "illegal abortion" is more controversial now in Texas than before Roe v. Wade was overturned.

Also, something can be illegal and have only civil penalties, which can be as high or as low as one likes, even 0, so the question of decriminalization versus legalization is not mere verbiage.

@Obie2.0 do you believe that it's OK to ignore a law if you believe the law is unjustified?

I do. The law is a means to achieve the highest good, not the highest good in itself. But what matters more, in terms of me not seeing the point of this question, is that many Americans likely think that, to judge from their behavior. It assumes as obvious notions about how Americans think that are not obvious and probably not how most of them think.

@Obie2.0 then you've realized the answer to the question How does this surprise you at all?.

Good question shouldn't be closed. Interesting to compare how/if immigration is controversial versus abortion, guns. How the media takes part in blowing up this narrative viz using words like undocumented migrants vs illegal immigrants.

Did you search for it? Something like "why is immigration an important/emotional/controversial/difficult to solve topic?".

@NoDataDumpNoContribution I asked an AI, which did not provide helpful answers. Googling the term you gave does not provide helpful answers, either.

It is better to talk about irregular immigration than illegal immigration. The US is a signatory to the Geneva Convention on Refugees (the 1967 Protocol, though not the original 1951 Treaty), which forbids criminal sanctions against those who are entering the country as refugees, even if they don’t follow the proper procedures (which in most cases they can’t, because there is no legal process to enter the US as a refugee).

@Allure Good. It wasn't clear from the question. Maybe it would be interesting to add why the answers you found weren't helpful to you (unless they were simply not relevant). That might clarify the point for those that aren't surprised at illegal immigration being controversial. I mean millions of illegal immigrants is quite a big number of human beings. The question what to do about them should be important, should it not?

@MikeScott Sometimes I also saw "unauthorized immigration" as a more technical and neutral term.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution unless they were simply not relevant <-- This. The question what to do about them should be important, should it not? Sure, but things like the linked question don't ask about what should be done about them.

There is a law and a lot of people think the existing law should be changed therefore there is talk about the topic of law. That is precisely what your example says, something is currently illegal, Kamela Harris proposes to change the law to make it legal. Other people believe the law is good as is. The topic is discussed. Classic politics. Where is the surprise?

@quarague I suppose you need more examples. Well, here's one I got from a quick Google search: https://www.reuters.com/world/us/us-campaign-ends-it-began-with-voters-focused-immigration-abortion-2024-11-05/. One of the summary points is Many Trump backers want to stem illegal immigration, which sounds kind of superfluous, because as the question says everyone ought to want to stem illegal immigration, because of that word 'illegal'.

@quarague nobody is suggesting that Kamala Harris or any mainstream politician wants to make it legal to cross the border without inspection; the proposed change is to remove the criminal penalties while leaving the existing civil consequences, including deportation, in place.

@Allure You still take it as a given that everyone wants to enforce the current law just because it is the current law. This is not the case. Slightly oversimplified. The Trump supporters would like to change reality to obey the current law. The Harris supporters would like to change the current law to make the current reality of illegal immigrants legal. They do not want to enforce the current law because they believe it to be wrong.

Doesn't "what should be done about them" also include "how should they be treated" and "how should they be persecuted"? The linked question seems to at least touch this. Illegal immigration surely can't be solved easily and forever so all the intermediate steps matter too.

@MikeScott there absolutely is a mechanism to enter the US legally as a refugee, but it's next to impossible to gain access to it because he numbers are severely limited (and the first Trump administration reduced the limit drastically, evidence that they are now only against illegal Immigration but immigration generally, despite their own family histories and in some cases personal histories).

@quarague then you should write that as an answer.


Example. The question title is "What is Kamala Harris' position on
decriminalizing illegal entry?", which does not make sense because
given that the entry is illegal, obviously Harris should be against
decriminalizing it (at least until she can change the law such
that the entry is no longer illegal).

This is probably a misunderstanding of what "decriminalizing" means. Decriminalization refers to make something not a criminal offense; it doesn't mean to making it legal. (And yes, decriminalization would require changing the law.) If illegal entry were decriminalized, illegal entrants would still be subject to deportation; they just wouldn't be criminally prosecuted and sentenced to a term in prison. For example, Mexico decriminalized illegal entry in 2008, but they obviously still have entry restrictions and deportations. And the US did not criminalize illegal entry before 1929, but the US had immigration restrictions before then. Overstay of people who entered legally is not currently criminalized in the US, but they are still being deported, and there is no outcry with it not being criminalized. So non-criminalized illegal entry is a perfectly viable arrangement, and not as crazy as you make it seem.

Yet illegal immigration was a major talking point in the recent (2024)
US elections.

"Talking point" doesn't necessarily tell you about a controversy over policy. A lot of times in politics, people will make straw man arguments and yell against an untrue or oversimplified version of their opponent's stance, but when you actually examine the details and nuances of the facts and both sides' stances, you will often see there is not that much disagreement on policy, or a disagreement on side details that are not obvious from the talking point. For example, when you examine the details of the question on decriminalization you mentioned above, you see that it is a relatively minor legal debate about whether illegal entry should be a criminal matter in addition to civil deportation. You will need to point out specific differences in official policy of two sides, and ask about each of those cases.
For example, no major political group in the US is generally against the deportation of people who are deportable, but Congress has only appropriated enough funding to deport only a very small fraction of them. So each administration needs to decide who to prioritize targeting with the limited resources. Is it to prioritize deporting violent criminals and leave the rest alone for now? Is it to prioritize deporting recent arrivals and leave the longer-term people alone for now? Is it to just deport whoever you come across first even if it will mean less resources to go after violent criminals? These are the substantive policy questions here, but they do not make for flashy "talking points".
A lot of times you will find that seemingly heated arguments are actually disagreements over definitions. "Illegal immigration" is a vague term, and most of the public are not well-versed in the nuances of the different immigration situations people can be in. Are people who are paroled into the US included in "illegal immigration"? Arguably not, since they were allowed to enter by the immigration officers, and parole is a power granted by law to the Executive Branch (though there are disputes in exactly how that power can be used). Are people who didn't have documents for entry but who have a pending application for asylum included in "illegal immigration"? US law allows them to apply for asylum, and they are not running away from deportation since they are already in deportation proceedings, but have not been ordered deported while waiting for adjudication of their asylum claims. It's easy to paint people in unusual immigration situations with a broad brush and call it "illegal immigration", and ask why they are not being deported, but when you look at the details of each type of situation, you will see that in many cases there is a legal reason why they are not subject to deportation.
